# Nginx config - serving index.html not working

Tags: nginx

I can't figure out how to redirect `/` to `index.html`.  I've gone through the threads on serverfault and I think I've tried every suggestion including:

- rewrite statements within `location /`
- `index index.html` at the `server` level, within `location /` and within static content
- moving `node.js` proxy statements to `location ~ /i` instead of within `location /`

Obviously something is wrong somewhere else in my configuration. Here is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes  1;

pid        /home/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    error_log   /home/logs/error.log;
    access_log  /home/logs/access.log combined;

    include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and my server config located in sites-enabled

```
server {
  root        /home/www/public;
  listen      80;
  server_name localhost;

  # proxy request to node
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;

    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3010;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    break;
  }  

  #  static content
  location ~ \.(?:ico|jpe?g|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|swf|xml|woff|eot|svg|ttf|html)$ {
    access_log  off;
    add_header  Pragma public;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
    expires     30d;  
  }

  gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "msie6";
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}
```

Everything else is working just fine. Requests get proxied to node correctly and static content is served correctly.  I just need to be able to forward requests made to `/` to `/index.html`.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you are trying to accomplish with the `root html` in the location block?  Is your index.html in /home/www/public/html? I've only used absolute paths.

Comment: I've removed that.  I was basically trying anything to get it to work and that was left over from one of the obviously failed attempts. Still no love though.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log? Can you tell if it is even trying to hit /home/www/public/index.html?

Comment: Nothing in the error log at all. Access log has `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404`. Nothing indicates it is even trying to hit index.html. The call eventually gets forwarded to my node server which displays an error page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, the `root` directive (inside the location block) didn't mention the **full path**. Also, a `;` is missing at the end of `index` directive (could be a typo, nginx usually catches these typos).

So, your server config located in sites-enabled would look like this (after the above two changes)...

```
server {
  root        /home/www/public;
  listen      80;
  server_name localhost;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # proxy request to node
  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;

    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3010;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    break;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }

# rest of the configuration
# ...
# ...

}
```

Comment: Oops, those were leftover from my last attempt. I've updated the conf file above to fix these typos.  Trying to access `/` still leads to a 404.

Comment: Okay, can you please put the `index` directive outside the location block? I'm updating my config file as well now. Thanks.

Comment: After seeing your other comment regarding the server log, I see what's wrong. I'm updating my config now for the updated configuration. Thanks.

Comment: No dice.  `localhost/index.html` works, `localhost` and `localhost/` still result in a 404.  Access log still gives 404, error log has nothing in it. `/` is still getting routed directly to my node server.

Comment: Try keeping `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy; }` above `location @proxy` directive.

Comment: Actually I think I found the problem... I have no idea what config nginx is actually using. I commented out the proxy entirely and then did a reload (`sudo /etc/init.d/nginx force-reload`) and now `/` works correctly, but so does my node server. I then did `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` and started nginx fresh and now the node server calls aren't working as expected. I then uncommented the proxy lines and can't get nginx to take on the updated config so node server is still broken...

Comment: Ah, finally figured out the problem. Nginx couldn't write to the `pid` file that I specified. Moving this file to a location it could write to allowed it to reload the config and your answer now works. Thank you so much for all of your help!